# Nokia QT SDK on archlinux

Tags: linux, qt, sdk, nokia, archlinux

Nokia realised qt sdk beta. http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/e920da1a-5b18-42df-82c3-907413e525fb/Nokia_Qt_SDK.html
Is it possible to run it on archlinux?

Hm, it is able to run, but unfortunately there is too new libpng version in archlinux.

Answer (score 1):

http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=33795

Or you can just clone download the [source](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/qt-qtcreator-prerelease#download) and build it yourself which will then use the newer libraries (but that may not work correctly).

As an arch user you should know how to use [AUR](http://aur.archlinux.org/index.php).  This really doesn't belong on stackoverflow, this is a question for the [arch forums](http://bbs.archlinux.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Just download the binary from here: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/downloads#lgpl

Comment: And like i said there is too new libpng in arch.